# Using Swig, how do I convert a const uint64_t * to a ruby array?

Tags: ruby, swig

I am using Swig to wrap a c library for use with Ruby.
There are several functions that return an array of of uint32_t and uint64_t as pointers.

For example something like:

```
const uint64_t *foo();
const uint32_t *bar();
```

I feel I should be able to map these into ruby arrays of Integer with a `%typemap`, but can't find a good example.

The default mapping is returning a swig pointer , ie `#<SWIG::TYPE_p_unsigned_long_long:0x0000000002204200>`

including stdint.i via `%include "stdint.i"`  seems to enable handling the uint64_t,  but not the pointers to them.

### Update

I tried the following typemap.  And it seems to work, is there a better way?

```
%typemap(out) const uint64_t* {
   VALUE arr;
   arr = rb_ary_new();
   VALUE v1 = INT2NUM(*$1);
   VALUE v2 = INT2NUM(*($1+1));
   rb_ary_push(arr, v1 );
   rb_ary_push(arr, v2 );
   $result = arr;
}
```

Comment: Are these single element pointers, or pointers to arrays?

Comment: pointers to arrays,  for example the documentation for one of the functions that returns `const uint64_t *` says it returns a pair of elements.

Comment: Doing a blanket mapping here for all pointers of that type seems like trouble, that could wildly misinterpret things, but it's a start. What about writing a thin C wrapper around those functions to bridge it?

Comment: yes, I had the same concern. I was thinking of doing a %clear after the definition that needs it, moving the typemap and definition to the end of the file,  or as you say, just writing a wrapper for those few functions.